# How to retrieve a list of verified domains and alias domains connected to a primary domain

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have looked at all to documentation and I cannot find any API to allow me to get a list of the domains from a Google Apps instance: is there really no query I can do to get all of the verified domains?

Comment: Just spotted a two-year old enhancement request that was acknowledge a year ago with no further updates, so I guess it's still non-existent: [link](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3430&q=label%3AAPI-Admin%20domains&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all domains using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) (Admin SDK) with the following get request.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/domains
```

The [documentation for this API method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/domains/list) includes the APIs Explorer at the bottom of the page (under the Try It! heading) that provides a convenient form to execute this API call. Enter 'my_customer' in the customer field.

The response will include a list of Domains and DomainAliases.